# Internal HDD not listed in explorer although mounted (ZFS filesystem)

Tags: mount

I cannot access my internal HDD via explorer, although it is mounted.
The filesystem of the disk is ZFS. What should I do to be able to access it by explorer?

There are two internal HDD, both ZFS. And the other internal HDD with the system (ubuntu) has docker and lxd. The one I try to see in nautilus has no data.

```
$ ls -lh /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 25 Nov  1 08:34 /dev/sdb9

$ ls -lh /mnt
total 512
drwxr-xr-x 2 simon simon 2 Okt 31 16:25 WD4TB



$ zfs list
NAME                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
default                            735K  26,6G       24K  none
default/containers                  24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/custom                      24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/deleted                    120K  26,6G       24K  none
default/deleted/containers          24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/deleted/custom              24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/deleted/images              24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/deleted/virtual-machines    24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/images                      24K  26,6G       24K  none
default/virtual-machines            24K  26,6G       24K  none
zfs-pool-WD4TB                     660K  3,51T       96K  /zfs-pool-WD4TB
zfs-pool-WD4TB/fs1                  96K  3,51T       96K  /mnt/WD4TB

:~$ zpool list
NAME             SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
default         27,5G   735K  27,5G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
zfs-pool-WD4TB  3,62T   924K  3,62T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

Comment: What do you mean by explorer? Are you meaning the default file app? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: So you can't navigate to `/mnt/WD4TB` in the file explorer?

Comment: @David that actually looks like LXD storage has been set up on a ZFS pool. This has nothing to do with the mounted datasets.

Comment: yes, in my case nautilus. Ignore the docker part. I added the info that there are two internal HDD, both ZFS. And the other internal HDD with the system (ubuntu) has docker and lxd.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a screenshot of how it looks in Nautilus.

Comment: Again I repeat all I asked was to make sure all details were given.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus (running by a non root user) doesn't have access to `/mnt`.
Try mounting the drive in a location within your home directory.

Comment: Great - short and precise answer! 